# PAM & /etc/security/time.conf

Tags: login, security, time, pam

I need to change the permissions access based on time in Ubuntu. I have a user called "miguel" and I want miguel not to gain access on Saturdays from 00:00 to 19:00 hours.

I read in web pages that this is simple:

1. I write this line in `/etc/pam.d/login`:

   ```
   account required pam_time.so
   ```
2. I write this line in `/etc/security/time.conf`:

   ```
   login;*;miguel;!Sa0000-1900
   ```

I saved this files with the changes.

But this not working!! I need help!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what is the behaviour your seeing?

Comment: Remember that `time.conf` only governs `login` times. That is, outside the specified window, `miguel` cannot login. However, if `miguel` is already logged in at the beginning of the window, nothing forces `miguel` to logout.